# Installing okhttp library

Tags: java, okhttp

I am trying to use the okhttp library in my codebase. Here is how I have it in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I bring it in like this, I get enforcer errors like this

```
Dependency convergence error for org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.20 paths to dependency are:
+-com.me:comp:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0
    +-com.squareup.okio:okio:3.2.0
      +-com.squareup.okio:okio-jvm:3.2.0
        +-org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.20
and
+-com.me:comp:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0
    +-org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.20
and
+-com.me:comp:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.11.0
    +-org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10
```

Now I have gotten this to work by having this in my pom instead.

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

However, why am I having to exclude something from 2 packages that are listed together from the same repo? Is this a bug? Shouldn't these 2 packages work fine together?
[Repo link](https://github.com/square/okhttp)